# Posting video + description to Tiktok API

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

I'm confused with the Tiktok API. Recently they announced that it's possible now to directly post a video with description. However when I look into their documentation (v2) I do not see anything related about posting videos.

Publishing with the [video web kit](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/web-video-kit-with-web/) is possible but I do not see any options for passing a description. Other social media scheduling tools are already posting directly to Tiktok. How are they doing this?

How is it possible that a big company like this has so little API documentation. It drives me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

yeah it's posible to post directly usign TIKTOK apis here's the documentation for that
https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/content-posting-api-get-started/

you can use https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/ API for the direct publish video and there is a lot more than just calling this API to publish video you can read it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that one of the examples in the Direct Posting documentation is broken, there's an extra comma in the last part of the json (video_url param) which makes the API respond with the following error:

"Invalid request parameters. Please ensure there are no unnecessary parameters in query or payload."

The broken example looks like this:

```
curl --location 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer act.example12345Example12345Example' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
--data-raw '{
  "post_info": {
    "title": "this will be a funny #cat video on your @tiktok #fyp",
    "privacy_level": "MUTUAL_FOLLOW_FRIENDS",
    "disable_duet": false,
    "disable_comment": true,
    "disable_stitch": false,
    "video_cover_timestamp_ms": 1000
  },
  "source_info": {
      "source": "PULL_FROM_URL",
      "video_url": "https://example.verified.domain.com/example_video.mp4",
  }
}'
```

The correct code would look like this:

```
curl --location 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/video/init/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer act.example12345Example12345Example' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' \
--data-raw '{
  "post_info": {
    "title": "this will be a funny #cat video on your @tiktok #fyp",
    "privacy_level": "MUTUAL_FOLLOW_FRIENDS",
    "disable_duet": false,
    "disable_comment": true,
    "disable_stitch": false,
    "video_cover_timestamp_ms": 1000
  },
  "source_info": {
      "source": "PULL_FROM_URL",
      "video_url": "https://example.verified.domain.com/example_video.mp4"
  }
}'
```

Hope this helps, as I spent a long time trying to figure out what was wrong with their example code.